# Retrieve the IDs of a user's friends and show in RecyclerView the data of each friend (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the Firebase, I have a “usuario” node with the data for each registered user. I want to retrieve the Ids of a user's friends and through these ID's show in RecyclerView the data of each friend (identifier, name and photo address).

My structure in Firebase:

[image]

I tried this code, but it doesn't work. the list is empty:

```
ref = ConfigFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase().child("usuarios"); //code in OnCreate

//My method
ref = ref.child(idUserLog).child("friends");

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot idFriends: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            DataUserFriend dataUserFriend = idFriends.getValue(DataUserFriend.class);
            String id = dataUserFriend.getIdUser();
            ref.child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        DataUser dataUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataUser.class);
                        listFriends.add(dataUser);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
        listFriendsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

What is wrong? or should i try another way?

**Solution:**

```html
ref = ConfigFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase().child("usuarios"); //code in OnCreate

//My method
ref = ref.child(idUserLog).child("friends");

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        
        final int numFriends = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        
        if(numFriends != 0){
            for (DataSnapshot idFriends: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                DataUserFriend dataUserFriend = idFriends.getValue(DataUserFriend.class);
                String id = dataUserFriend.getIdUser();
                ref =  ConfigFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase().child("usuarios").child(id);
                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            DataUser dataUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataUser.class);
                            listFriends.add(dataUser);
                            
                            if(listFriends.size() == numFriends){
                            listFriendsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `listFriendsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` should happen in the same method that updates `listFriends`.

So:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot idFriends: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            DataUserFriend dataUserFriend = idFriends.getValue(DataUserFriend.class);
            String id = dataUserFriend.getIdUser();
            ref.child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        DataUser dataUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataUser.class);
                        listFriends.add(dataUser);
                        listFriendsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

---

If you want to call `listFriendsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` only when all friends have been added to `listFriends`, you can keep a count of how often the inner `onDataChange` has been called and compare that to the number of friend IDs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I followed the suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `SingleValueEvent` listener on database reference object due to which the callback isn't getting fired immediately. You should create a `Query` and add the `SingleValueEvent` listener for it. For example:

```
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios");
    Query query = mDatabase.child(idUserLog).child("friends");
    query .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             // Code to parse and display data
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
     });
```